# Create multi-column dropdown part of a listbox or combobox

Tags: shieldui

I've managed to create a multi-column droplist part for a combobox as shown in the image.

[image: Multi-column combobox]
However I really don't like the way I've done it because I basically changed the default class (sui-listbox) which would mess up all comboboxes and listboxes.

```
.sui-listbox {
    width: 450px !important;
}

<script id="ddl-template" type="text/x-shieldui-template">
<div class="ddl">
    <table border="0">
        <col width="130">
        <col width="80">
        <col width="100">
        <col width="140">
        <tr><td>{RecNo}</td><td>{PONo}</td><td>{Date}</td><td>{Stamp}</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I do need this feature in lots of places.

And oh! I posted another message about adding header to the dropdown part.  It would be wonderful to be able to add column headers to the multi-column dropdown.

Thanks,

pt

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom class for your ComboBox using the [cls setting](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/combobox/javascript/api/settings/cls), and change the CSS selector to something like:

```
.sui-combobox.my-combo .sui-listbox { … }
```

so it applies only the the listbox inside your specific combo(s) having this class.